How to save the values on smart contract by triggering the functions without using private key on Node js?
How do I save the values on a smart contract by triggering the functions without using a private key on Node.js?
Only i have the contract address With only contract address, how can i save the values on a smart contract by triggering the functions ?

You cannot send a transaction to an EVM-based blockchain without signing it with a private key.

Thanks Alexander :)
